# How to write sample Python class as Java simple bean?

Tags: java, python, oop, multilingual

I learning **Python** and writing classes with this language seems me more complicated. I don't understand everything. Java code is longer but more clearly than **Python** magic methods. How to write code classes in **Python** most similar as to the one below in **Java**:

```
public class Person {
    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private int age;

    public Person(String name, String surname, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getName() { return name; }

    public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }

    public String getSurname() { return surname; }

    public void setSurname(String surname) { this.surname = surname; }

    public int getAge() { return age; }
    
    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    @java.lang.Override
    public java.lang.String toString() {
        return "Person{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", surname='" + surname + '\'' +
                ", age=" + age +
                '}';
    }
}
```

I understand that **Python** does not have **full encapsulation**, so it is not possible to create a private field, for example, but I looking for the best class pattern for this language :) How to write the **most effective class** in this language?

Comment: https://realpython.com/lessons/sample-classes-python-v-java/

Comment: Great ! Thanks for solution :)

Answer (score 1):

Private methods are by conventions in Python. You can use `_variabe` to indicate something should be treated as private. Using double underscores, such as `__variable`, mangles the name. The variable is still accessible, but it's more difficult and enforced by the Python interpreter.

Typically you don't need getters and setters in Python. You can write your class as:

```
class Person:

    def __init__(self, name, surname, age):
        self.name = name
        self.surname = surname
        self.age = age

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Person{{name={self.name},surname={self.surname},age={self.age}}}'


john = Person('John', 'Smith', 44)
print(john)
Person{name=John,surname=Smith,age=44}
print(john.age)
44
```

If you later need to add functionality to setting a property, you can do so by adding `@property` annotations and then adding getters/setters, changing the old public variable to a private one that is modified by the properties:

```
class Person:

    def __init__(self, name, surname, age):
        self.name = name
        self.surname = surname
        self.age = age
        
    @property
    def name(self):
        return self._name
        
    @name.setter
    def name(self, value):
        self._name = value[0].upper() + value[1:]
        
    def __str__(self):
        return f'Person{{name={self.name},surname={self.surname},age={self.age}}}'

j = Person('john', 'smith', 14)
print(j)
Person{name=John,surname=smith,age=14}
print(j.name)
John
```

This allows a property to change from just a field to something processed by a function, without any of the code accessing it needing to change.

Comment: You edit object using "dict notation"? This look strange :) I understand that you don't create new dictionary, you only pass parameter to constructor. Do you must to know key names?

Comment: The braces `{}` in the string is f-string notation. It simplifies printing variables in strings. It's not a dictionary. Also the lines under the print statements are what they print out. The only reason I put braces around the whole thing is that's how you had it in your `toString()` example in the question.